# Storyboard viewcontroller resize

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

i just copy and paste all the view from iPhone storyboard and paste it on iPad storyboard,everything works fine but the base view from every view controller was locked and couldn't resize.any idea on this?

the property to adjust width,height,x,y was turn to grey and unclick-able.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to your project file in xcode -> summary tab -> ipad deployment info -> main storyboard. set that to your storyboard file. it should cause all your viewcontrollers to resize to the ipad size.